# InAppBrowser Plugin not working after update from Cordova 3.3 to 3.4 Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I updated an Android application to Cordova 3.4 from 3.3. Now the inAppBrowser or redirect to external browser no longer work

An example of a redirect in my code is:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://www.example.net/subscribe/index.html', '_blank', 'location=yes');" data-role="button">Subscribe to example</a>
```

The API docs for 3.4 say to use `var ref = window.open()`

API docs: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/dev/doc/index.md

I tried that with no luck but I recognize that is simply adding the redirect to a variable, which is not what I need. Just a simple `window.open`

Has anyone run into this issue? How did you fix it? Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the error I am getting from the LogCat when I click on a URL

```
03-26 15:18:47.146: D/PluginManager(21722): exec() call to unknown plugin: InAppBrowser
```

Comment: What API docs are you talking about?

Comment: Those related to the InAppBrowser plugin. I added the link to the question. Thanks!

Comment: The syntax should be the same between version of Cordova as the platform was changed, not the plugin. Have you tried removing and reinstalling the plugin?

Comment: Yes I tried several times. I even build an entire new project and transferred the files over.

Comment: did you solve you're issue ? Since I have installed this plugin, I can't even launch my PhonegapApp

Comment: I never did :/ I just switched back to 3.3